# How to position half of image out of the div responsive

Tags: css, image, positioning, responsive

I would like to position the icons where the red square is. But I have tried the position: relative and position absolute but I dont understand why its not working.

[image]

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="wrap">
                <img class="blockico" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icons/catering150.png">
                <h4>Catering</h4>
                <a href="url">The Menu</a>
                <br>
                <a href="url">Today's Menu</a>
                <br>
                <a href="url">Gallery</a>
                <br>
                <a href="url">Festivities</a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>

    .wrap {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #e9e9e9;}

    .blockico {
position:absolute;
top:-50%;}
```

Comment: Try using a pixel value instead like top: -100px; Does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this isn't working for you; I plugged it into a Fiddle and (while it doesn't behave the way I think you'd want) it seems to move the image up just fine. Here's a fiddle of a slightly different approach (not using position attributes; just applying a negative top margin) that might get you closer.

https://jsfiddle.net/35aohm3y/

```
.wrap {
  margin-top:50px; /* push the wrap down a bit. You might not need this */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;}

.blockico {
  background:#666; /* added just for demonstration purposes */
  margin-top:-50px; /* and push the image up a bit */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I noticed that my gulp didnt update the css file! Your solution works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative margin to pull the image up and out.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.options ul,
.options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.options>div {
  margin: 50px 0;
  /* for demo */
}

.options .wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.blockico {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row options">
  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="wrap">
        <img class="blockico" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fc0">
        <h4>Restaurant</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="url">The Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Today's Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Festivities</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="wrap">
        <img class="blockico" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fc0">
        <h4>City Club &amp; Garden</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="url">The Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Today's Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Festivities</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="wrap">
        <img class="blockico" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fc0">
        <h4>Catering</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="url">The Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Today's Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="url">Festivities</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

update css `blockico`

```
.blockico {
    position:absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    left: 50%;
}
```