# How to postion an image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an image in top of my div like in the picture bellow, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out whats wrong with my css.

[image]

```css
#testimonials-cards-container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 43px;
}

.testimonials-cards {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 50px 26px 33px 27px;
    height: 337px;
}

#testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img{
    width: 200px;
    display: table;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSeven">
        <div id="testimonials-cards-container" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="testimonials-cards">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png
" alt="">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're going to need some `position: absolute;` stuff on your image, then give it a negative top, like `top: -50%` or something. The testimonial-cards or the parent is going to need `position: relative;` also. Or you could use a negative margin on the image, like `top: -50%;`. You could also use translate and move it up 50%. A few ways to skin this cat depending on what you're after.

Comment: Add ```position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); left: 50%;``` to the image class ```#testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img``` ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283530/how-to-position-half-of-image-out-of-the-div-responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this pen](https://codepen.io/alesc/pen/GRJoEbb). I'm using `position: relative;` and `top: -50px;` on the `img` element to position it outside the card.

Cheers!

Comment: position: relative; that's what i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it. Align it center (`text-align:center`) then negate the top margin by half the image size (plus an extra 50 for some additional padding).

```css
#testimonials-cards-container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 43px;
}

.testimonials-cards {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 150px 26px 33px 27px;
    height: 337px;
    text-align:center;
}

#testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img{
    width: 200px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSeven">
        <div id="testimonials-cards-container" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="testimonials-cards">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png
" alt="">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use margin, you need to mind : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> The `top` and `bottom` margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single `margin` whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

here is an example using padding :

```css
#testimonials-cards-container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 43px;
    margin-top:150px;
}

.testimonials-cards {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 50px 26px 33px 27px;
    height: 337px;
    padding:0.01px;/* collapsing margin */
}

#testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img{
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSeven">
        <div id="testimonials-cards-container" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="testimonials-cards">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png
" alt="">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you want to align your `image` and `label`, i added another `div.credential-holder` with `display: inline-grid` to display contents in grid format and `margin-top: -100px` to overlay image on top.

```css
#testimonials-cards-container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 43px;
}

.testimonials-cards {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 337px;
    margin-top: 100px; /*add this 100px to fill in -100px from div.credential-holder*/
    text-align: center;
}

.credential-holder{
  margin-top: -100px;
  display: inline-grid;
}

#testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSeven">
        <div id="testimonials-cards-container" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="testimonials-cards">
                <div class="credential-holder">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png
" alt="">
                    <h1>Test, Test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to align texts in center and position absolute to align the image.
Css Code is

```
        #testimonials-cards-container {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: 43px;
    }

    .testimonials-cards {
        box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 30px;
        margin: 50px 26px 33px 27px;
        height: 337px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #testimonials-cards-container .testimonials-cards img{
        position: absolute;
        top: -50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        display: table;
        margin: 10px auto;
        transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Html Code is

```
        <div class="sectionSeven">
            <div id="testimonials-cards-container" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="testimonials-cards">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png
    " alt="">
                    <h1>test</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

You can use this approach at any place in your code. You do not have to worry about height or width of container any more.